How do I install the Gnome extensions that Ubuntu comes with by default?
I recently installed Ubuntu Server 24.04 arm64 and installed Gnome on it, but it has the same settings you would find on Debian, just stock Gnome with no extensions. How can I install all of the extensions and settings that regular Ubuntu Desktop comes with?
Note: I was not able to find an Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 image for arm64, only Ubuntu Server.
